# INSERT INTO SELECT from UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert-select

I need to select some values from a table to be updated, and then update them right away. Furthermore, I need to insert one new record in a table for each updated record. To select records and update I am using a structure like

```
UPDATE TableA SET SomeField = 1 OUTPUT RecordID FROM TableA WHERE RecordID IN
(    
    SELECT TOP @Something RecordID FROM TableA    
)
```

Now, for the insert part, I would like to wrap the `UPDATE` statement into an `INSERT INTO SELECT`, thus taking advantage of the `OUTPUT` clause. However, SQL complains when I do

```
INSERT INTO TableA SELECT ( RecordID , GETDATE() ) FROM
(
    UPDATE TableA SET SomeField = 1 OUTPUT RecordID FROM TableA WHERE RecordID IN
    (        
        SELECT TOP @Something RecordID FROM TableA        
    )
)
```

Can't I do it all in one statement, even with the `OUTPUT` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA SET SomeField = 1 
OUTPUT inserted.RecordID, GETDATE() into TableA (RecordID , DT)
FROM TableA 
WHERE RecordID IN
(        
    SELECT TOP @Something RecordID FROM TableA        
)
```

Just not sure - you're trying to insert updated rows again  ?

Comment: No, I want to get `RecordID` and insert a new row with different data.

Comment: You will get record ids there of all the updated rows and you can insert that in another table or the other column.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to use output to insert the updated rows from one table to another:
However I cannot make that syntax you are using to work.
Please check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you *could* try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (RecordID, Value)
SELECT RecordID, GETDATE()
FROM OPENQUERY(
  yourserver,
  'UPDATE TableA
  SET SomeField = 1
  OUTPUT inserted.RecordID
  WHERE RecordID IN (SELECT TOP (5) RecordID FROM TableA)'
)
```

But there's a couple of issues with the approach:

1. You'd need to create a linked server `yourserver`.
2. The 'remote' query wouldn't be very swift.
3. You'd have hard time replacing `TOP (5)` with `TOP (@Something)`. Actually you'd most probably have to turn the entire statement into a dynamic query. (That's right, you'd have to put the already dynamic UPDATE inside another dynamic query.)

I expect, with the last issue the one-statement limitation would finally be broken.

So, instead, why not have it like this:

```
DECLARE @tmpRecords TABLE (RecordID int);

UPDATE TableA
SET SomeField = 1
OUTPUT inserted.RecordID INTO @tmpRecords (RecordID)
WHERE RecordID IN (SELECT TOP (@Something) RecordID FROM TableA);

INSERT INTO TableA (RecordID, SomeDateColumn)
SELECT RecordID, GETDATE()
FROM @tmpRecords;
```